# Merge and push to protected branch without the web interface

Tags: git, github, merge, push, bitbucket

With protected branches on bitbucket and github, 
after all check and approvals pass,
is there a way to pull, merge, and push the protected branch using only git locally and avoiding the website?

Also, avoid using a buypass such as `--force` to ensure that these checks have indeed passed.

**bitbucket**

- require a minimum x successful builds
- require at least x approval

**github**

- require status checks to pass before merging
- require pull request reviews before morging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the GitHub [Documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request/):

To merge a pull request into a protected branch with required pull request reviews enabled, the pull request must meet the review policy. In this policy, a pull request:

- Must have one approved review
- Can't have any reviews that request changes

You can merge a pull request to the protected branch if it satisfies the above conditions. Simply use

```
# 123 is the pull request number
git fetch origin pr/123/head:newbranch
git checkout protected_branch
git merge newbranch
git branch -D newbranch
```

Since the branch is a protected branch, you can't directly commit to it. You can only commit to it via pull requests. Also using of `--force` is strictly prevented in protected branches.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help!